# What is the best way to serve (page) content with ajax in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a custom Wordpress theme and I'd like it to preserve the DOM when changing pages. It is working already but the way I serve the content via Wordpress feels very ugly.

I have chosen to replace all links to hash links with javascript for graceful fallback:

This code does that for all links in the menu and for all links with the class ajax:

```
var baseLength = $footer.data('url').split('/').length;

$menu.find('a').add('.ajax').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href').split('/');
        url[baseLength - 1] = '#' + url[baseLength - 1];

        return url.join('/');

    });
});
```

By using baseLength I make sure to add the # after the wordpress path (it could be at server.com or server.com/deep/path/to/wp).

Now I bind the ajax call to he hashchange event (for preserving back button, etc.)

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
    //fade current page out
    $boek.children().fadeOut(speed);
    //get new page
    $.get(location.href.replace(/#/,'') + '?ajax=true', function(data) {
        $boek.html(data).children().hide().fadeIn(speed);
    });
});
```

I now make a request for the page in the URL (after removing the # to have the full path again).

### The ugly part

I also append the get var 'ajax' to the url, this way I can serve only the main content via Wordpress:

inside my header.php:

```
<?php if(!$_GET['ajax']) { ?>
<!doctype html>
...
<?php } ?>
```

(And the same thing in Footer). This way I only get the content besides the header/footer/etc. It would be a lot cleaner to build this into a function imo. Does Wordpress makes it possible to do something like this? I can't seem to find it.

I'm only interested in the AJAX'ing content of pages, I need the content and I would also like the title of the page (which I don't have right now).

Comment: Have you tried using $.load()? Refer to the docs for specifics but you can do something like $.load('newpage#content') which will load the content but only return the html in whatever id="content" is.

Answer (score 0):

For single pages / posts just request the URL via an ajax get, and then parse the content out you need from the returned html. You will still get back header / footer etc, but you wont use any of it in your page view.

If you want to request something like an archive, or just get portions of pages, you need to create a seperate method within say functions php and invoke that via ajax, specifically through wp_ajax; http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

What I do in cases like this is grab any display variables such as post count, categories, tags etc within my header file, and then pass these vars to ajax using wp_localize_script; http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

eg:

```
wp_localize_script( 'site', 'omanuAjax', array( 
        'ajaxurl'       => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'tag'           => get_query_var('tag'),
        'cat'           => $useCat,
        'single'        => $wp_query->is_single,
        'search'        => $wp_query->is_search,
        'searchquery'   => $searchQuery
    ));
```

Then simply parse those vars as POST vars within your post loop and return a json encoded array of post data that you can then display as you like using javascript.